# Can I put the packaged file into another directory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am wondering if I can put a packaged JAR or WAR into another directory using Maven. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a directory as your delivery location:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>internal.repo</id>
            <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
            <url>file:///home/me/path/to/my/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Just run maven as follows

```
mvn clean deploy
```

I suspect this is not what you're looking for...It's kinda pointless.... Running the *install* goal places the same artifact in the following default location

```
$HOME/.m2/repository
```

Some further guidance on why you want to do this might furnish a better answer